# integrating own restful service with views

Tags: node.js, angularjs, get

I have a webpage written in angularjs that shows some items. when I click on next page it does an ajax request like this:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/posts/' + lastTime})
```

This action is called by a button `ng-click='loadMore()'` and the lastTime is taken by the last item in the returned array.

and then in my model, it simply returns n items before that time. Now suppose that when the user clicks on next page, the url changes as well, like this:

```
example.com/posts/1379494126
```

What would happen is that my nodejs express server will obviously return a json object and not the jade view as it's done when doing `GET /`.

What is a common approach to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you performing the GET request? Using `$http`? Also, what action is associated with the "Next" button? Is it an `a` tag masquerading as a button - if so what is its `href` attribute? If it is a simple button, then what happens on click? Is a function called (using `ng-click`)?

Comment: Something's not right - the URL will only change if you explicitly have code to change it, for example through `$location` service or `href` attribute of the anchor tag. Merely using `ng-click` followed by a `$http` service based GET request will not change your URL...

Comment: i know that, but that's not the issue. what i mean is that *once* the url will be changed, and it will look like example.com/posts/593765 if the user bookmarks it, it will not open because my webserver will respond with a json rather than a view